# Не получается отправить фото через postman

Tags: node.js, postman

В общем отправляю фото через form-data, выдает это:
{
"message": "Cannot destructure property 'img' of 'req.files' as it is undefined."
}
Вот код получения фото:
const {img}=req.files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты просто в основном `index.js` нарушил порядок подключения. Связанное с загрузкой img должно идти сразу после `app.use(express.json())`. Например:

```
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static(Папка, куда файлы собираются)
app.use(fileUpload({}));
```